# How to hide an interface in another interface?

Tags: android, oop, design-patterns, kotlin, interface

I want to write an Android library, which in turn uses another Androd library.

Let's say I want to write `libHigh` which uses another `libLow`

There is an interface in libLow:

```
interface LowLevelInterface{
   fun methodA()
}
```

and I implement this in my higher level library libHigh:

```
open class OpenClassImpl : LowLevelInterface {
  override fun methodA(){//..}
}
```

It is an 'open' class, because later in app layer I expect to extend from `OpenClassImpl`. 
**But I dont want to make the interface 'LowLevelInterface' visible for later upper app level usage.**

How can I hide the interface from libLow for the upper app level?

Comment: Make `private interface LowLevelInterface`. But in this case you should write all its children classes in one file.

Comment: May be you can split you codebase in multiple project, declaring `LowLevelInterface` as `internal` and using `OpenClassImpl` in a different module... see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html#modules

Comment: @TarasParshenko I dont have access to LibLow

Comment: So you could create own private interface and extend `LibLow`

Comment: @TarasParshenko You mean `private interface NewPrivateInterface :  LowLevelInterface {}` ?

Comment: You may try using `Shadow` plugin for Gradle to inline the LibLow classes under a hidden package inside your LibHigh.

The other approach is to bundle the LibLow JAR in resources of your LibHigh jar and use a custom classloader to load the code, it is possible for JVM, may not work with Android

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your existing code whether this will work, or how much effort it will be, but you could have a property implementing the interface instead of doing it directly:

```
open class OpenClassImpl {
    // or protected/private
    internal val lowLevelImpl: LowLevelInterface = { 
        // can access privates of OpenClassImpl here
    }
}
```

and change the relevant calls to pass it.